# Accessing camera and image processing with Open-CV in Android as background process

Tags: android, opencv

I have seen with the help of Android Open-CV library we can do image processing.

But for doing so we have to import CameraBridgeViewBase library, this implements CvCameraViewListener and by initializing objects we can cave access to the camera frames. Below is the sample code which I have used from 15-Puzzle Game provided by Open-CV community.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_camera);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Log.d(TAG, "Creating and setting view");
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.show_camera_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(mOpenCvCameraView.CAMERA_ID_BACK);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(S);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mOpenCvFrontCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.hidden_front_camera);

   mOpenCvFrontCameraView.setCameraIndex(mOpenCvCameraView.CAMERA_ID_FRONT);
    mOpenCvFrontCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mPuzzle15 = new Puzzle15Processor();
    mPuzzle15.prepareNewGame();
}
```

My query is, Is there a way where we can have background process which will access camera and do image processing and provide the x,y of screen co-ordinates to other process.